# Puppeteer Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded

Tags: node.js, npm, chromium, puppeteer

I used `npm i puppeteer` as stated in the [Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#getting-started)
and I'm getting the following error:

**(node:2066) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"
    at Launcher.launch**

when im trying this example (also from the docs):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Also in the documentation:

> Note: When you install Puppeteer, it downloads a recent version of Chromium (~170MB Mac, ~282MB Linux, ~280MB Win) that is guaranteed to work with the API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting. I had a similar issue on a previous Ubuntu setup, chromium wasn't downloading. Now, I'm installing on a new server and when I `npm install puppeteer`, it did not show it was downloading Chrome during installation. However, running `node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js` said Chromium was already in `/root/.cache/chrome/linux-1095492` folder.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

After many attempts I finally found the answer [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2173):

```
sudo npm install puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

As @vsync pointed out, this only works for linux

Comment: This answer is specifically for linux, which makes it useless for many developers, because windows OS is still very dominant

Comment: But ubuntu bash for windows is what will make it usefull

Comment: @tramada Still Linux ;)

Comment: npm v7 does not have `--unsafe-perm` or equivalent anymore https://github.com/npm/feedback/discussions/121

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue. I was trying to use puppeteer inside a docker container e this made it work.

Answer (score 151):

I only managed to fix the issue by manually installing Chromium after much searching and trying most of the suggestions:

```
node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
```

To ensure the correct installation of the newer version, I recommend checking the directory **node_modules/puppeteer**. If you find that the installation file's extension is .mjs, please use it accordingly.

```
node node_modules/puppeteer/install.mjs
```

Comment: My local modules had `puppeteer-core` instead of `puppeteer` but the solution worked the same.

Comment: This worked on me for a mac, but I also needed to unset an env var. `unset PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD && node ./node_modules/puppeteer/install.js`

Comment: worked for Mac m1

Answer (score 47):

By default, the `puppeteer` module will run its install script (`node install.js`). However, in my case, I enabled `ignore-scripts=true` in my `~/.npmrc` file, so it was never executed.

In that case, you have to run the command yourself:

```
node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
```

To check: `node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-<your_chrome_version>/` should exist now.

Comment: That command worked for me, but I didn't set the ignore-scripts to true. I did a straight npm install. Weird!

Comment: I had to clean up some disk space and the .cache folder got removed.  Running `npn i puppeteer` did not re-run the install script.  Running manually dl into the .cache folder, and my project is running again.

Answer (score 16):

for linux:

1- you must have installed chromium browser using this command :

> $sudo apt install -y chromium-browser

2- you have to get the excutable path of chromium using this command :

> $which chromium-browser

3-put the executable path as an argument to the launch function :

```
   const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
   (async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
   headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

    await browser.close();
    })();
```

Answer (score 7):

Confirming solutions presented here almost work. Here's my setup. Ubuntu 16.

Install chromium browser from command line then:

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  Finally had some progress after reading this!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it worked after deleting node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and running npm install again.

Answer (score 3):

**I solved it like this**:

`const browser = await puppeteer.launch({  executablePath: "./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-656675/chrome-win/chrome.exe"});`

note the **win64-656675** in the path, if you're on a different operating system you will need to point to the appropriate folder.

puppeteer version: 1.16.0

Answer (score 3):

After couple of hours googling and reading many comments and discussions, trying several approach finally I resolved the problem with this solution.

```
OS: Windows 10
node: 14.16.1
puppeteer: 7.0.1
```

I saw in the `node_modules/puppeteer/` folder and found that there isn't any `.local-chromium` folder so I created this path manually

```
node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-<your_chrome_version>/chrome-win
```

Then I downloaded the chromium browser from [this link](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) (your_chrome_version) and so copied it to the path so that you need to see the chrome.exe in this url

```
node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-<your_chrome_version>/chrome-win/chrome.exe
```

That's it. it worked for me.

Comment: If the folder exist you can check the path, and files, or you  can rename it and do the steps.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't have Chrome installed on your system.

For installing Chrome

```
sudo apt install -y chromium-browser
```

then after that add an executable path.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
  headless: false
});
```

Comment: "Note: When you install Puppeteer, it downloads a recent version of Chromium (~170MB Mac, ~282MB Linux, ~280MB Win) that is guaranteed to work with the API" so you need to make sure the Chromium version you dl will work with your version of Puppeteer.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still facing this problem again. Then goto node_modules folder then into puppeteer and in lib where you find launch.js open the same file and search for executablepath then change its null value to your chrome or chromium desired path.

For me the path as follows :

> /home/Nightwing/node_modules/puppeteer/Launcher.js

Answer (score 0):

On Windows works installing as global

```
npm i puppeteer --g
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how I solved it**

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'], // this made it work for now
  });
```

By simply having `ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']` done the trick

**Source:** [Troubleshoot](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md)

Answer (score 0):

I just delete the `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD` variable from the Dockerfile and that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd point in [Amr Hussein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12165904/amr-hussein)'s answer helped me to solve a similar Problem where I got the following error, whenever I executed my script outside the project directory:

```bash
throw new Error(`Could not find Chromium (rev. ${this.puppeteer.browserRevision})
Error: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1083080).
```

I will use that in my last step.

But let's start at the very beginning:

If you install `puppeteer`, Chrome will be automatically downloaded. But it is recommended that you change the default location of Chrome with a Configuration file.

1. Create your project directory where `puppeteer` should be installed
2. Go inside this directory.

   If you are `root`, change to the normal user of the system.
3. As recommended in the [documentation](https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration#changing-the-default-cache-directory), create a file named `.puppeteerrc.cjs` and paste in the following code:

   ```js
   const {join} = require('path');

   /**
    * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
    */
   module.exports = {
     // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
     cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
   };
   ```

   This will change the default location of Chrome to your project directory.

   Now Chrome will be stored inside the project directory in the `.cache` directory.
4. Install `puppeteer`:

   Here you can basically hit `enter` until the init is done.

   ```bash
   npm init
   ```

   ```bash
   npm i puppeteer
   ```
5. On Unix, make sure all the necessary dependencies are installed.

   You can find the list on the [Troubleshooting](https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix) page.
6. Find `Chrome` inside the `.cache` directory of your project directory and figure out the full path.

   Add the `executablePath:` of the Chrome executable to your script:

   ```js
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '/home/drake/my_puppeteer_project/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-1083080/chrome-linux/chrome'
    });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `executablePath()`

```
import { executablePath } from "puppeteer";


const options: PuppeteerLaunchOptions = {
 ...
 executablePath: executablePath(),
};

await puppeteer.launch(options);
```

Remove from Dockerfile

```
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me.

It turns out that the Chromium download URL (https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) can be blocked if you are sitting on a VPN. If this is the case, the installation script (`node_modules/puppeteer/install.js`) will say that it successfully downloaded to `~/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/<version>` but all it does it create an empty folder.

**The solution for me was to switch to a different location with my VPN.**

Here is the status for this issue in the Puppeteer repository: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/10013