# Failed to launch chromium headless using puppeteer on Ubuntu 16.04 AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, puppeteer, headless-browser

I have a microservice in which one of the API is generating PDFs (3 pdfs based on type passed as a parameter). I have used puppeteer package to generate the PDF. Works as charm on my local system.

When I try to run the same microservice on EC2 ubuntu 16.04 server, it is unable to launch chromium headless. I have used "npm i puppeteer" and as per my understanding, it should bring chromium headless on its own as dependency.

The microservice is running fine, but the issue is in fetching chromium by puppeteer.

Error

```
Error: Could not find browser revision 800071. Run "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install" or "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn install" to download a supported Firefox browser binary.
```

Also, I am unable to find **".local-chromium/linux-{version}/linux-chrom"** inside **"/node_modules/puppeteer/"**

So, my understanding is that chrome never got installed

I am comfortable with docker as well. I am running other microservices in docker only. So, if anyone can suggest some workaround using docker, that can also work.

Concerned codepart from the microservice

```
async function createPDF(baseFile, inp) {
var templateHtml = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(process.cwd(), `utilities/${baseFile}.html`),
    "utf8"
  );

  var template = handlebars.compile(templateHtml);

  var html = template(inp);

  var milis = new Date();
  milis = milis.getTime();

  var pdfPath = path.join(process.cwd(), `${baseFile}.pdf`);

  var options = {
    width: "1100px",
    height: "1380px",
    // format: "A3",
    headerTemplate: "<p></p>",
    footerTemplate: "<p></p>",
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    margin: {
      top: "10px",
      bottom: "10px",
    },
    // printBackground: true,
  };

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
    headless: true,
  });

  var page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${html}`, {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  });

  //   await page.addStyleTag({
  //     content:
  //       "@page:first {margin-top:10px; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:30px; margin-left:10px;}",
  //   });

  const pdf = await page.pdf(options);
  await browser.close();
  return pdf;
}
```

Output of **npm i puppeteer**

```
 npm i puppeteer

> puppeteer@5.3.1 install /home/ubuntu/vendor-module/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

(node:18339) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /home/ubuntu/vendor-module/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/install.js:138
                    catch {
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at download (/home/ubuntu/vendor-module/node_modules/puppeteer/install.js:35:7)
(node:18339) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

[Puppeteer Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997175/puppeteer-error-chromium-revision-is-not-downloaded) - This link helped me to debug that I need to run install.js in puppeteer manually.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3443 - This link for everything else.

Also, apt-get install libgbm-dev

Comment: For people looking into docker - https://medium.com/@christopher.talke/using-node-puppeteer-with-docker-without-wanting-to-smash-your-keyboard-ed78e9529a8b

Also, the article has a reference at the beginning of a simple deployment. So, that will be also helpful